# Why creating new module in Orchard 1.7.2 referring to system.web.mvc 3.0 version? why cant it refer to 4.0 version of mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I have created a module in Orchard 1.7.2. Looking at the web.config file, i found that its still referring to 3.0 verison for system.web.mvc dll and also System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0.

All other mvc related dlls are under 4.0.0 version. Please let me know if we can make any configuration change so that when new module is created, it refers to mvc 4.0 version.

Thanks,
Ruja

Comment: There should be binding redirects in place. Does this cause you any real problems?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to add my existing project as a module under Orchard and since my project is on MVC 4.0, its giveing my some reference errors and I have to change all the references to make it work. If some how we can change the configuration so that while creating module, it refers mvc 4.0 version, it would be great help.

Comment: I don't understand. What prevents your module from referencing 4.0? That web.config file is yours, you can do whatever you want with it.